# Can "ekrasieren" be translated as "to exterminate"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, austrian, archaism

In [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/57001/23839) there is following German text:

> Diese müßten ekrasiert und hiezu kein Mittel gescheut werden.

Can "ekrasieren" be translated as "to exterminate"?

I could not find this word in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/eklatieren?ls=ekrasieren&s=eklatieren). One obscure [web site](https://www.enzyklo.de/Begriff/Ekrasieren) claims that "ekrasieren" is synonymous with [vernichten](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=vernichten) and [zermalmen](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=zermalmen).

Comment: Das ist ein richtig altes Wort, findet sich aber zum Beispiel im Begriffsverzeichnis http://ciml.250x.com/archive/marx_engels/german/mew/band27_403.pdf dieses Buches (auf Seite 744)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have to admit that I have never seen this word in German, even though I'm a native speaker.

It's obviously a loanword from French. Today nobody uses this word, except maybe in a very special context, but in the 18th and 19th century the educated elite would have understood it.

The word that you're searching is *écraser*. The Cambridge Dictionary offers the [following translations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/franzosisch-englisch/ecraser):

- to crush (an insect, a rebellion,...)
- to squash (an insect,...)
- to mash (potatoes,...)
- to run over (with a car,...)
- ...

In your context, *to crush* seems to be the most appropriate word.

Comment: I only see "unbarmherzig verfolgen" (persecute without pity) in the original. But french military terms are very commom at that time, in Russia as in Austria, as shown by "The good soldier Schweijk" by Hasek. (Cavallet, Menage, Bataillon, desertieren, **Sabotage**).

Comment: I am not belittling "unbarmherzig" -- is this more "systematisch" or "grausam" ? "Crush" can also be both, so I agree.

Comment: *except maybe in a very special context* as a French with near zero knowledge of German I immediately recognized this word. The special context may be a French making a funny (**and gentle**) remark about something/someone (a team for instance) being crushed, in a German context (to show that the crush was how we perceive our Germans neighbors and friends: Ordung und Systematism). A simple 1:2 score in football would not be *ekrasieren*. 7:1 (and the one was let go for honor) would clearly be.

Comment: @WoJ: I'm convinced that nobody would understand you, Most Germans who speak sufficiently well French and have no problem with "écraser" would still struggle when hearing "ekrasieren". (Identifying the word in a written text is much easier.)

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt: sorry, I was not clear: what I meant is that French  could (conceivably) use that when speaking **among themselves** (for the reasons, and in the context I explained above). Of course a German speaking French would never use that when speaking German.

Comment: @WoJ: I had thought that you were thinking of saying something like "Hast Du gesehen, wie die Bayern gestern von PSG ekrasiert wurden?" (i.e.: **French fan -> German fan**). Une "victoire écrasante" dans le foot est définitivement un exemple bien plus sympa qu'un avion qui s'est écrasé sur le tarmac. ;)

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt: I had something like that in mind *"tu as vu comment le Bayern a ekrasiert la Juventus?"* (sorry I have no idea about football, do not hunt me if the choice of the teams was wrong :))

Answer (score 4):

[Meyers Konversationslexikon](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Ekrasieren&werk=Meyers) (1885-1892) lists the word as given in your question and offers *zermalmen* (to crush) and *vernichten* (to destroy, to annihilate) as explanation.